# Why is npm attempting to use a package version not referenced in my package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I've created an Angular + .NET 5 web application and am trying to run `npm i` to install the packages.  When I do, I get this following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: badgemanagement.admin.webui@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"13.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.2.5" from @angular/compiler-cli@13.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-07T14_52_08_376Z-debug.log
```

As you can see from my package.json file below, I'm not referencing `@angular/compiler-cli@13.2.5` or `@angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.5`.  If I were to guess, it's probably attempting to use the global cli version installed which is likely 13.2.5, but why would it completely ignore the one referenced in the package.json?  Sure, I could use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`, but am I really supposed to tell it to ignore dependencies when the correct dependencies are referenced in the package.json?  It doesn't make sense to me.  I've done an `npm cache clean --force`, but that didn't help.  What's the "correct" way to handle this scenario assuming I want to use this specific version?

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run myapp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "13.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "13.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "ini": "^1.3.7",
    "jasmine-core": "3.8",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "typescript": "4.5.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "url-parse": ">=1.5.0",
    "lodash": ">=4.17.21"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is because of the caret `^` which will try to get the minor release. Try by removing the `package-lock.json` & remove the caret before the version number.

Alternatively you can also try `yarn install`

Comment: You're absolutely right!  The carets got removed during the upgrade process from Angular 8 -> 13 (The VS 2019 template starts you off with Angular 8).  Good job picking that up.  Thanks!